# Converting image format with Vulkan/GPU?

Tags: vulkan

I have an image on the host that is in "premultiplied" B8G8R8A8 format, which means each R8, G8 and B8 component needs to be divided by A8 (and multiplied by 255).  See for example `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html

I'd like to transfer and translate the image to a device `VkImage` in the usual `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` format.

Normally I'd do this by creating a host `VkBuffer` and then transfering the image to a `VkImage` with `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage`, but I need to swizzle the components around and apply that division as part of that process.

How can I do that so that the translation occurs quickly using the GPU?

Comment: If some image has premultiplied alpha, should you just use the data that way? That is, are you sure you *need* to un-premultiply it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Not a bad thought.  I guess I could, but it kind of messes with the architecture when mixed with other images that are not premultiplied.  I'd need to keep track of which ones are and aren't and then write two versions of sampler code.  I guess I was thinking it would be easier to having all the images normalized early to the same format.

Comment: "*it kind of messes with the architecture when mixed with other images that are not premultiplied*" Does it, though? The whole point of premultiplied alpha is that you use it as you normally would for the color, and the math just works out with the right blending. Color images with transparency that you expect to be used with blending ought to be premultiplied. And if they don't have transparency... there's no premultiplication to worry about.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It sounds like you're suggesting using a premultiplied format for all images.  Normally when a library (like say libpng) loads an RGBA PNG image, it won't be in premultiplied format.  Somewhere you would need to divide through by the alpha channel during loading/transfer.  OTOH I assume `VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState` could be adapted to deal with premultiplied format by adjusting the various `VK_BLEND_FACTOR_*` settings as appropriate.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "premultiplied format". Premultiplication is about the *meaning* of the data, about what its contents represent. It is not part of any "format"; a PNG can be premultiplied if it was generated that way. Premultiplication is something you do to values of data. And yes, it affects blending, but only because it is meant to. If you have an albedo image that has holes in it that you expect to use blending with when drawing, it should be premultiplied. If the image doesn't have holes in it, then "premultipled" is not even a question you can *ask*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Right, technically you can store any 8-bit numbers you want in the RGBA channels of a PNG (losslessly) and they could mean whatever you want, but if I open a PNG with an image viewer, it will assume they are not premultiplied and display them to the screen as such.

Comment: I'm not sure I see your point. If the image has whatever data it has. If you are being asked to display it, then you display it as is. It isn't wrong to display an image with premultipled alpha as what its data says that it is.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `VK_FORMAT` premultiplied, and you want the transition done on GPU, then I'd imagine that compute shader is the way to go. Screen quad rendering is also possible, but harder than a compute shader.

However, if you want everything in one format, shouldn't it be so in the first place, and not when the app actually runs?

Comment: The image is generated at runtime, so the image doesn't exist before the app runs.

Comment: Then if you can change code that generates image. Also, if you want it to be done on GPU, then I imagine its generated very often, like every frame or so. In which case, compute shader it is. Just have a thread for each pixel, image load/store, divide by alpha (its all floating point, no need to multiply by 255).

Comment: The code that generates the image is a library called Blend2D: https://blend2d.com, rewritting the library to generate a different format would be too time consuming.  It turns out the library has a host-side optimized BLPixelConverter class for this task: https://blend2d.com/doc/classBLPixelConverter.html I might try that out before going the computer shader route.  I'm not sure all my target platforms support compute.

Answer (score 0):

Premultiplied alpha is done to [solve a problem](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre). If you undo the premultiplication (to the extent possible, since an alpha of 0 leads to the loss of the original color information, and even small values of alpha can make reconstructing the color impossible), you will be *reintroducing the problem*.

That's probably not what the artist wanted when they used premultiplication.

As such, your code should be binary on this issue with regard to transparency. Either your code should assume post-multiplied alpha (in which case you will encounter the problem) or it should assume pre-multiplied alpha (in which case you will not encounter the problem). If you're assuming post-multiplied, and someone slips pre-multiplied in on you, that's an art pipeline failure and it should be resolved there.

Garbage in, garbage out.

Many image formats don't recognize the concept of "pre-multiplied" on a format level. That is, they don't have premultipled format identifiers or settings or something. An image is "premultiplied" invisibly.

Some formats do have such flags; KTX does. But some formats intrinsically assume it. For example, BC1 compression with 1-bit alpha always generates a color of 0 with an alpha of zero. So in linear filtering, you will always effectively get pre-multiplication. And since it's a compressed format

If you are dead-set on undoing premultiplication, then you can use a compute shader with image load/store to do that. But it'd probably be best to do it at the tool level, rather than at runtime.